# How to return using the Usercontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Basically i have a Main Window page and a Setting page which is the User Control. When i click the **Setting button** on the main window, the **Grid** in the main page will show the setting page user control.

Meanwhile, there is a **Cancel button** on the setting page. When i click on it, the setting page user control will disappear from the **Grid** and return how it is at the main window. So what can i write in my user control code? Or any other ways? Thanks.

My main window:

```
<Grid Name="grid1"> 
  <TextBlock  Text="Hello World" />
  <TextBlock Text="Welcome" />
  <Button Name="settingBtn" Content="Setting" Click="settingBtn_Click" />   
</Grid>
```

My main window code cs:

```
 private void notifyBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        UserControls.NotifySetting Set = new UserControls.NotifySetting();
        grid1.Children.Clear();
        grid1.Children.Add(Set);

    }
```

My Usercontrol page:

```
<Grid > 
  <RadioButton Name="r1" Content="Red Color Font" />
  <RadioButton Name="r3" Content="Blue Color Font" />
  <Button Name="saveBtn" Content="Save" Click="saveBtn_Click" />  
  <Button Name="cancelBtn" Content="Cancel" Click="cancelBtn_Click" />  
</Grid>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How you can hide the settings user control?

Comment: i have a grid with some data ABC....when i click a button, the grid will show the user control . when i click the cancel button in the user control, the grid will show back the ABC.

Comment: I would create and add the usercontrol in the constructor of the main window and save the reference in a class variable. The buttons then only change the `Visibility` attribute.

Comment: Can you kindly provide me some link of sample? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this in the cancel button click event:

```
 (this.Parent as Panel).Children.Remove(this)
```

Comment: thx, but i encounter another problem. After i click the cancel, the user control is disappear but original child in the grid1 also gone because of the grid1.Children.Clear(). Do you have any solution to get back my cleared grid child?

Comment: Just remove the usercontrol instead of clearing the grid. That is what the line I posted does. It takes the usercontrol's parent (which is the grid container and casts it to a panel, panel is just a base container class which both Grid and Stackpanel inherit from), then it removes itself.